# WiFi выключен аппаратно Lenovo B590

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, железо

Не работает *wifi*-модуль. Стоит Ubuntu 14.04.

В системе вижу сообщение - WiFi выключен аппаратно.

В lspci адаптер видно:

> Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 b/g/n.

Если делаю `ifconfig wlan0 up`, появляется интерфес. Но в системе изменений нет.

Что пробовал:

- Переустановка драйвера
- `rfkill unblock all`
- `modprobe wl`
- `apt-get install ideapad-laptop-dkms`

Аппаратного выключателя на ноутбуке нет. В биосе ноутбука модуль включен.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: *Но в системе изменений нет* — а каких изменений вы ожидаете?

Comment: того что кнопочка включить активной. либо будут видны беспроводные ссети.

Comment: при загрузке с *live*-{cd|usb} адаптер работает?

Comment: нет. не работает.

Comment: «цена вопроса» — [от 300-400 рублей](https://market.yandex.ru/search.xml?cvredirect=2&text=usb%20wifi%20%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0&how=aprice&deliveryincluded=1). только имеет смысл перед покупкой опробовать прямо в магазине.

Comment: вы про свисток? Мне не подходит. В системе адаптер виден. Нужно его как то включить.

Comment: [здесь](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) смотрели?

Comment: Да кончено. Много черго перепробывал.

Comment: А Fn+F2 или что-нибудь подобное пробовал?

Comment: хардварный свитч скорее всего привязан к Fn+F5 или еще какой-нибудь комбинации на клавиатуре

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в загрузчике. Там была опция acpi=off после изменения её на acpi=on всё заработало.

Comment: А как это поменять?

Comment: нужно отредактировать загрузчик груб. я делал это через grub-customizer.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```